# Change value on submit

Tags: javascript, html

I'm gonna keep this simple.
I'm helping a friedn out with here website. It started as a simple HTML site and later on developed a simple php booking form.
As it looks today, and yes don't ask me why :D

```html
<input type="radio" name="datum" value="2020-05-10 kl. 09:00-16:00">2020-05-10 kl. 09:00-16:00<br />
<input type="radio" name="datum" value="2020-05-16 kl. 09:00-16:00">2020-05-16 kl. 09:00-16:00<br />
<input type="radio" name="datum" value="2020-06-07 kl. 09:00-16:00">2020-06-07 kl. 09:00-16:00<br />
<input type="radio" name="datum" value="2020-06-13 kl. 09:00-16:00">2020-06-13 kl. 09:00-16:00<br />
<input type="radio" name="datum" value="2020-06-28 kl. 09:00-16:00">2020-06-28 kl. 09:00-16:00<br />
<input type="radio" name="datum" value="2020-07-04 kl. 09:00-16:00">2020-07-04 kl. 09:00-16:00<br />
<input type="radio" name="datum" value="2020-08-01 kl. 09:00-16:00">2020-08-01 kl. 09:00-16:00<br />
<input type="radio" name="datum" value="2020-08-09 kl. 09:00-16:00">2020-08-09 kl. 09:00-16:00<br />
<input type="radio" name="datum" value="2020-08-29 kl. 09:00-16:00">2020-08-29 kl. 09:00-16:00<br />
<input type="radio" name="datum" value="2020-09-06 kl. 09:00-16:00">2020-09-06 kl. 09:00-16:00<br />
<input type="radio" name="datum" value="2020-09-12 kl. 09:00-16:00">2020-09-12 kl. 09:00-16:00<br />
<input type="radio" name="datum" value="2020-09-20 kl. 09:00-16:00">2020-09-20 kl. 09:00-16:00<br />
<input type="radio" name="datum" value="2020-10-11 kl. 09:00-16:00">2020-10-11 kl. 09:00-16:00<br />
```

She want to change it so there's only 10 available reservation on each date, and when a new booking is sent that value are changed like this

```html
<input type="radio" name="datum" value="2020-05-10 kl. 09:00-16:00">2020-05-10 kl. 09:00-16:00 - Reservation left 10 of 10<br />
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="datum" value="2020-05-10 kl. 09:00-16:00">2020-05-10 kl. 09:00-16:00 - Reservation left 9 of 10<br />
```

etc etc. Hopefully you understand what i mean :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this interacting with a database, because if it is then you could limit the statement to only display 10 results maybe? For example SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Reservations; or you could use: SELECT * FROM Reservations LIMIT 10;

Comment: No, an database is not used. Only a PHP that send a mail both to the reserver and the sites owner.

Comment: oh sorry, i have more experience in database technologies

Comment: How much work would it be to set up a databas? I have no experience of that so i have no clue.

Comment: do you use a web host for this website?

Comment: Yes, she use one.com

Comment: well is there a 'cpanel' in the dashboard, because there should be links to pages such as domains, if there is then look for a link such as phpmyadmin or configure db/database

Comment: Oh that sound way to complicated for me :/

Comment: oh, how do you manage this site do you use a file manager or wordpress? and also i'm like 13 so yh

Comment: I've never managed this site before since it's not mine. But i guess it's done with Microsoft Visual Studio from start and later on edited with file manager.

Comment: why don't you ask your friend for information about their website eg: on their web host what plan they use (shared, vps, dedicated), if they use a shared or vps hosting plan tell them to set up a database because it will help with data mangement. If they use a dedicated hosting plan, then ask them what server software they are using (Apache, NgInx, Windows Server), and tell them to search up how to set up an sql database depending on whichever.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. This is the info i got
nginx/1.14.0
Database client: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev
PHP-version: 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3

Comment: they will be able to set up a mysql database then

Comment: Any tips where i can read more about phpMyAdmin and the purpose i'm looking for

Comment: You can go on the official website for PHP (http://www.php.net), or go on https://www.w3schools.com/sql/ (they have tutorials on SQL)